# I want to merge array[0] and [1] into an integer array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array named id_list. It has index 0,1

```
id_list[0]= 200, 201, 202, 203
id_list[1]= 300, 301, 302, 303
```

I want to merge `index[0]` and `index[1]` into an integer array.
I used `.join()` but it merges all element including `,` into the array.

```
var arr = id_list[0].join(id_list[1]);
console.log(arr[0]);  // result => 2
console.log(arr[1]);  // result => 0
console.log(arr[3]);  // result => ,
```

I just want as **`id_list= [200, 201, 202, 203, 300, 301, 302, 303]`**.
I don't want the `,` value.

Please help me how to merge them.

Comment: when you do `id_list[0]= 200, 201, 202, 203`, only `203` is added to the `id_list` array. Did you mean `id_list[0]=[200, 201, 202, 203]` ?

Comment: @JanDvorak based on the way she's getting single characters including commas in her console log, I suspect she actually means `id_list[0]="200, 201, 202, 203";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example and the way you're getting individual characters in your results suggests that your values are actually strings, like this:

```
var id_list = [];
id_list[0] = '200, 201, 202, 203';
id_list[1] = '300, 301, 302, 303';
```

If that's the case, your first step needs to be converting them to actual arrays. You can do that by just splitting on the `,` but a regular expression that removes the spaces as well will give you a cleaner result. `/ *, */` will look for a comma with optional spaces before or after it:

```
id_list[0] = id_list[0].split(/ *, */);
// now id_list[0] is an array of 4 items: ['200', '201', '202', '203']

id_list[1] = id_list[1].split(/ *, */);
// now id_list[1] is an array of 4 items: ['300', '301', '302', '303']
```

Then you can use `concat()` to join your arrays into a single array:

```
var arr = id_list[0].concat(id_list[1]);
```

I suspect this is more like the output you're expecting:

```
console.log(arr[0]); // shows 200
console.log(arr[1]); // shows 201
console.log(arr[3]); // shows 203
console.log(arr[5]); // shows 301
```

Comment: An explanation on the regex would be nice ;-) At this point it looks like a comment block.

Answer (score 3):

Try use `Array.prototype.concat`

```
var newArr = id_list[0].concat(id_list[1]);
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kR6df/)

In your case you can just do:

```
id_list = id_list[0].concat(id_list[1]);
```

Read about it **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)**

Answer (score 3):

Use method [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```
id_list[0].concat(id_list[1])
```

Comment: Please don't link to w3schools. You can use MDN instead.

Comment: There is a lot of misinformation and bad examples on W3schools. Some of them have been fixed, but a lot of them haven't and new keep appearing.

Comment: @llya aah you fixed the link my +1 for you... :) But i agree with @ JanDvorak though...

Comment: @PSL The first time I heard about the errors on W3School. I will take it into account